# Creating Tweet Display Box in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the following code to generate a Tweet input box which takes in text/video/image/emoji. And they can be in different combinations.

I am not sure how to generate a tweet display box which shows the final display containing text/image/emoji ? I understand I might need to put the different inputs in an array or some sort but what after that. My current code for display side is performing nothing and I am not sure where to go from here.

I am looking for display box to be of following form after a `Submit Button`:

[image]

Code `components/EmojiPicker.js` has:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Picker } from "emoji-mart";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const EmojiPicker = ({ onSelect }) => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    return (
      <>
        <Button
          onClick={() => setShow(oldState => !oldState)}
          style={{ width: "30px", height: "30px", borderRadius: "4px", border: "3px solid", display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center",
            background: "transparent"}}>
          ej
        </Button>
        {ReactDOM.createPortal(
          show && <Picker onSelect={onSelect} />,
          document.body
        )}
      </>
    );
  };

  export default EmojiPicker
```

Code `components/FileInput.js` has:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react'

const FileInput = ({ onChange, children }) => {
    const fileRef = useRef();
    const onPickFile = event => {
      onChange([...event.target.files]);
    };
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          width: "35px",
          height: "35px",
          borderRadius: "3px"
        }}
        onClick={() => fileRef.current.click()}
      >
        {children}
        <input
          multiple
          ref={fileRef}
          onChange={onPickFile}
          type="file"
          style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default  FileInput
```

Code components/tweetboxImgInp.js as:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'


const ImgIcon = () => (
    <svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
      <path d="M14 13l4 5H6l4-4 1.79 1.78L14 13zm-6.01-2.99A2 2 0 0 0 8 6a2 2 0 0 0-.01 4.01zM22 5v14a3 3 0 0 1-3 2.99H5c-1.64 0-3-1.36-3-3V5c0-1.64 1.36-3 3-3h14c1.65 0 3 1.36 3 3zm-2.01 0a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v14a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h7v-.01h7a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V5z" />
    </svg>
  );

  export const Img = ({ file, onRemove, index }) => {
    const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
      if (file) {
        setFileUrl(URL.createObjectURL(file));
      }
    }, [file]);

    return fileUrl ? (
      <div style={{ position: "relative", maxWidth: "230px", maxHeight: "95px" }}>
        <img
          style={{
            display: "block",
            maxWidth: "230px",
            maxHeight: "95px",
            width: "auto",
            height: "auto"
          }}
          alt="pic"
          src={fileUrl}
        />
        <div
          onClick={() => onRemove(index)}
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            width: "20px",
            height: "20px",
            borderRadius: "50%",
            background: "black",
            color: "white",
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center"
          }}
        >
          x
        </div>
      </div>
    ) : null;
  };

  export default ImgIcon
```

And `App.js` has:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import ImgIcon, {Img} from './components/tweetboxImgInp'
import EmojiPicker from './components/EmojiPicker'
import FileInput from './components/FileInput'
import "emoji-mart/css/emoji-mart.css";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [pics, setPics] = useState([]);
  const textAreaRef = useRef();
  const insertAtPos = value => {
    const { current: taRef } = textAreaRef;
    let startPos = taRef.selectionStart;
    let endPos = taRef.selectionEnd;
    taRef.value =
      taRef.value.substring(0, startPos) +
      value.native +
      taRef.value.substring(endPos, taRef.value.length);
  };
  return (
    <div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", border: "3px solid", borderRadius: "5px", width: "600px", minHeight: "200px", padding: "20px"}}    >
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", flex: 1, border: "1px solid", borderRadius: "5px", margin: "0px"}}>
        <textarea
          ref={textAreaRef}
          value={text}
          style={{ flex: 1, border: "none", minHeight: "150px" }}
          onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap", background: "fbfbfb"}} >
          {pics.map((picFile, index) => (
            <Img key={index} index={index} file={picFile} onRemove={rmIndx =>
                setPics(pics.filter((pic, index) => index !== rmIndx))}/>))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", marginTop: "20px" }}>
        <div style={{ marginRight: "20px" }}>
          <FileInput onChange={pics => setPics(pics)}>
            {/* <ImgIcon /> */}
            Tes
          </FileInput>
        </div>
        <EmojiPicker onSelect={insertAtPos} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Edit: I am good with the display box accepting only 1 media file, text and few emoji. It will surprise me if I am the only one in 2019 looking to do it for fun.

Comment: Can you create a minimal `stackblitz` or `codesandbox` of your app?

Comment: I don't think I have a clue to take the inputs from that box to generate anything :). I can create a lot of stuff but taking the input from that box to create another box is like enigma and no amount of google search is leading me anywhere.

Comment: What are we talking about here? Do you want your users to be able to combine whatever number of text, emoji and images/videos together and save that as a tweet to display? Twitter uses a `div` with `contenteditable` instead of an `input`. It works just like a rich text editor and it's really complex to build one from scratch. But if you're willing to have 3 separate inputs (one each for text, emoji and media files) that should be easier. If you combine (1 text string + 1 sequence of emojis + 1 media file) is that enough for your project?

Comment: (1) I was wondering if you can provide me link if available for such rich complex text editor. Being in 2019 I would assume that is already done by multiple people. I couldn't be the first one wanting to do it for fun. (2) If not available, I am fine as long as only text, few emoji and 1 media file is taken as input also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working Example

Click the codesandbox button to view the demo

[image: Edit competent-currying-u59b5]

The tweet display component is pretty straightforward. Its a flexbox column with two parts. First part of the column contains the tweet. The second part of the column contains the list of images/media elements. Emoji is part of the text component.

---

[image]

---

### Tweet Display Component

```
const Tweet = ({ tweet: { text, images } }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      margin: "20px",
      border: "1px solid grey",
      width: "600px",
      padding: "20px",
      borderRadius: "3px"
    }}
  >
    <div>{text}</div>
    {images.length > 0 && (
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          background: "fbfbfb",
          padding: "30px 0"
        }}
      >
        {images.map((img, i) => (
          <Img key={i} file={img} index={i} isSingle={images.length === 1} />
        ))}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

For more info checkout [this css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) article to get more info on css flex layout

Comment: (1) Wow you are amazing .. however the code doesn't take multiple image inputs but seems like you intended to create multiple image inputs ? (2) After NPM start and file upload where do they get stored because I realized after I close the browser the tweets are gone. i.e. does the browser have it's own temporary storage?

Comment: It does take multiple images, each image should be different. While selecting images, you can select multiple images. Yes, this code doesn’t send any data to server. It just resides in memory while the browser session lasts. If you want to persist, you can do a multi part form upload of images to a server and save them, to retrieve them later